# Will the Fucidin Cream 2%, prescribed for impetigo on face, help clear-up pimples and zits too?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, impetigo, abscess-lesions, pimple

I've always struggled with acne, but recently, I noticed that my typical cystic acne's pimples and zits were different than usual. Not only were they redder and larger, but they were blister-filled and oozed clear liquid (not pus) -- very bubbly like in appearance, and then crusted over with a large gross yellowish-brown scab. Hideous.  Come to find, some of the odd pimples on my face were actually impetigo (a staph infection commonly seen in small children).

Anyway, I'm not sure how or why I got it, but my Dr. prescribed me the **Fucidin Cream 2%** to apply 4 times daily for 2 weeks to the impetigo abscesses.

**I was wondering if this antibiotic cream would also clear up my pimples and zits?**